# Detect when a tab is closing with cross browser support including Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I need to tell a 3rd party site that my site integrates with when a tab is closing.  This seems easy enough for Safari, Chrome & Edge but is not working in Firefox

```
function close_the_chat(){
  fetch(`https://example.com/closethething`);
}
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  close_the_chat();
});
```

I have also tried the event onunload, but it does not work in firefox.

How can I include firefox for this functionality?

Comment: window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    close_the_chat();
    e.returnValue = '';
});

Comment: You can add a return  to the close_the_chat to be null to be assigned to  e.returnValue

Comment: this doesnt work in firefox @AlaaKaddour

Comment: check this page , every browser has a specific behaviour , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#browser_compatibility

Comment: They do, although that chart is mostly about how to trigger an alert box.  I don't want an alert at all.  just for close_che_chat to be called.